# Table View is not displaying Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

you can download this project from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1daW4veZAI21b8TqKFHauSFTboHKJceaG/view?usp=sharing)
Execute this Program Clicking on button"Click here to sell your Gold now" enter the

username :hermon_yonaito@bullionscope.com

password :Wau2017?

**Issue -1**

It will launch you to dashboard. Select "Transaction History" that is not displaying record. Check why record is not displaying?And to display the record in view Controller?

**Issue-2**

**The second issue** is on selecting Profile the ProfileViewController.m is executed.On updating the user profile updateButtonTap function is executed.It does not update.It remains buffering.How to perform profile update?

here is ProfileViewController.m

```
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface ProfileViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProfileViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentUser = [SingletonClass sharedSingletonClass].settingsDictionary[@"User"];
    selectedValues=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [paramDict setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"request"];
    [paramDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentUser.user_id] forKey:@"user_id"];

    [GeneralWebservices webserviceMainSplashCall:paramDict webserviceName:Webservice_Profile OnCompletion:^(id returnDict, NSError *error) {

        if ([returnDict[@"success"] intValue] ==1)
        {

            [self setProfileData:returnDict[@"data"]];
            provinceList=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:returnDict[@"provincedata"]];
            questions1Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:returnDict[@"questiondata"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self get_register_data];


        }
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

    }];


}
-(void)setProfileData:(NSMutableDictionary*)dataDict
{
    profilePicImageView.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:dataDict[@"image_file_thumb"]];
    [firstNameLabel setText:dataDict[@"first_name"]];
    [lastNameLabel setText:dataDict[@"last_name"]];
    [dateOfBirthLabel setText:dataDict[@"user_dob"]];
    [postalAddressTextfield setText:dataDict[@"user_address"]];
    [mobileTextfield setText:dataDict[@"user_mobile"]];
    [question1Textfield setText:dataDict[@"user_answer_1"]];
    [question2Textfield setText:dataDict[@"user_answer_2"]];
    [LLGButton setTitle:dataDict[@"user_llg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [provinceButton setTitle:dataDict[@"user_province"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [districtButton setTitle:dataDict[@"user_district"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [villageTextfield setText:dataDict[@"user_village"]];
    [question1Button setTitle:dataDict[@"user_question_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [question2Button setTitle:dataDict[@"user_question_2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self callforDistrict:@"get_district.php" idForItem:dataDict[@"district_id"]];
    [self callforLLG:@"get_llg.php" idForItem:dataDict[@"llg_id"]];

    [selectedValues setObject:dataDict[@"user_question_1_id"] forKey:@"user_question_1"];
    [selectedValues setObject:dataDict[@"user_question_2_id"] forKey:@"user_question_2"];
    [selectedValues setObject:dataDict[@"province_id"] forKey:@"user_province"];
    [selectedValues setObject:dataDict[@"district_id"] forKey:@"user_district"];
    [selectedValues setObject:dataDict[@"llg_id"] forKey:@"user_llg"];


}
-(void)callforDistrict:(NSString*)serviceName idForItem:(NSString*)idForItem
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self getdistdata:idForItem];
    });

}
-(void)callforLLG:(NSString*)serviceName idForItem:(NSString*)idForItem
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self getIIL:idForItem];
    });


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [profileScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 700)];
}

- (IBAction)uploadPictureButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"Open Gallery",
                            @"Take Photo",
                            nil];
    popup.tag = 1;
    [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}

- (IBAction)provinceButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSMutableArray *provinceNames=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSMutableDictionary*pro in provinceList)
    {
        [provinceNames addObject:pro[@"province_name"]];
    }
    LGActionSheet *sheet=[[LGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Province" buttonTitles:provinceNames cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil];
    sheet.tagOfSheet=2;
    sheet.heightMax=300;

    sheet.delegate=self;

    [sheet showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];
}

- (IBAction)districtButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSMutableArray *names=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSMutableDictionary*pro in districList)
    {
        [names addObject:pro[@"district_name"]];
    }

    LGActionSheet *sheet=[[LGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select District" buttonTitles:names cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil];
    sheet.heightMax=200;
    sheet.tagOfSheet=3;
    sheet.delegate=self;
    [sheet showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];
}

- (IBAction)LLGButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSMutableArray *names=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSMutableDictionary*pro in llgList)
    {
        [names addObject:pro[@"llg_name"]];
    }

    LGActionSheet *sheet=[[LGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select LLG" buttonTitles:names cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil];
    sheet.heightMax=200;
    sheet.tagOfSheet=4;
    sheet.delegate=self;
    [sheet showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];


}

- (IBAction)villageButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}

- (IBAction)question1ButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSMutableArray *ques1=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSMutableDictionary*pro in questions1Array)
    {
        [ques1 addObject:pro[@"question_name"]];
    }
    LGActionSheet *sheet=[[LGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Question 1" buttonTitles:ques1 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil];
    sheet.tagOfSheet=5;
    sheet.heightMax=300;

    sheet.delegate=self;

    [sheet showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];

}

- (IBAction)question2ButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSMutableArray *ques2=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSMutableDictionary*pro in questions1Array)
    {
        [ques2 addObject:pro[@"question_name"]];
    }
    LGActionSheet *sheet=[[LGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Question 2" buttonTitles:ques2 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil];
    sheet.tagOfSheet=6;
    sheet.heightMax=300;

    sheet.delegate=self;

    [sheet showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];


}

- (IBAction)updateButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [selectedValues setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"request"];
    [selectedValues setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentUser.user_id] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [selectedValues setObject:postalAddressTextfield.text forKey:@"address"];
    [selectedValues setObject:mobileTextfield.text forKey:@"user_mobile"];
    [selectedValues setObject:question1Textfield.text forKey:@"user_answer_1"];

    [selectedValues setObject:villageTextfield.text forKey:@"user_village"];

    [GeneralWebservices webserviceCallWithData:selectedValues webserviceName:Webservice_ProfileUpdate dataToPost:imageData imageName:imageName OnCompletion:^(id returnDict, NSError *error) {
        if ([returnDict[@"success"] intValue] ==1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
            [alert setTitle:@"Updated Successfully"];
            //[alert setMessage:returnDict[@"message"]];
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
            [alert show];
        }
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

    }];
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(LGActionSheet *)actionSheet buttonPressedWithTitle:(NSString *)title index:(NSUInteger)index
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (actionSheet.tagOfSheet==2)
        {
            [selectedValues setObject:provinceList[index][@"province_id"] forKey:@"user_province"];
            [provinceButton setTitle:provinceList[index][@"province_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [districList removeAllObjects];
            [llgList removeAllObjects];
            [districtButton setTitle:@"District *" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [LLGButton setTitle:@"LLG *" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [selectedValues removeObjectForKey:@"district"];
            [selectedValues removeObjectForKey:@"llg"];

            [self callforDistrict:@"get_district.php" idForItem:provinceList[index][@"province_id"]];


        }
        else if(actionSheet.tagOfSheet==3)
        {
            [selectedValues setObject:districList[index][@"id"] forKey:@"user_district"];
            [districtButton setTitle:districList[index][@"district_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [llgList removeAllObjects];
            [LLGButton setTitle:@"LLG *" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [selectedValues removeObjectForKey:@"llg"];

            [self callforLLG:@"get_llg.php" idForItem:districList[index][@"id"]];

        }
        else if(actionSheet.tagOfSheet==4)
        {
            [selectedValues setObject:llgList[index][@"id"] forKey:@"user_llg"];
            [LLGButton setTitle:llgList[index][@"llg_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if(actionSheet.tagOfSheet==5)
        {
            [selectedValues setObject:questions1Array[index][@"question_id"] forKey:@"user_question_1"];
            [question1Button setTitle:questions1Array[index][@"question_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else if(actionSheet.tagOfSheet==6)
        {
            [selectedValues setObject:questions1Array[index][@"question_id"] forKey:@"user_question_2"];
            [question2Button setTitle:questions1Array[index][@"question_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    });



}
-(IBAction) returnTextField:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    switch (popup.tag) {
        case 1: {
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0:
                    [self openPhotoLibraryButton:self];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    [self openCameraButton:self];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (IBAction)openCameraButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        picker.allowsEditing = false;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:true completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Camera is not connected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
- (IBAction)openPhotoLibraryButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        picker.allowsEditing = true;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:true completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    imageData=[[NSData alloc]init];

    if ([info[@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] isEqualToString:@"public.image"])
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
        if (!image)
        {
            image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        }
        NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

        image=[SettingsClass rotateImageAppropriately:image];        

        NSString *imageNamewithformat = [imagePath lastPathComponent];

        imageName=@"assets.jpg";

        NSString *Imageformat = [imageNamewithformat substringFromIndex: [imageNamewithformat length] - 3];
        if ([Imageformat isEqualToString:@"JPG"]||[Imageformat isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
            imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.33f);
            imageName=@"assets.jpg";
        }
        else if ([Imageformat isEqualToString:@"PNG"]||[Imageformat isEqualToString:@"png"])
        {
            imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            imageName=@"assets.png";
        }
        else
        {
            imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.33f);
            imageName=@"assets.jpg";
        }
        [profilePicImageView setImage:image];
    }
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    CGPoint temp = [textField.superview convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:nil];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){

        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 264-(self.view.frame.size.height-moveUpValue-35);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = self.view.frame.size.height-temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 264-(self.view.frame.size.height-moveUpValue-35);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 352-(self.view.frame.size.height-moveUpValue-100);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 352-(768-moveUpValue-100);
        }

    }
    if(animatedDis>0)
    {
        const int movementDistance = animatedDis;
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f;
        int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
        [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset( self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset( self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset( self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }
        else {
            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset( self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}


- (IBAction)backtohomeview :(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)getdistdata:(NSString*)idForItem
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    NSString *strURL;


    strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bullionscope.com/Gold_Phase3/webservices/get_district.php?request=ios&province_id=%@",idForItem];


    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"900e1577-4876-cd9a-d24c-cb0631b4a1fb" };


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                       // [self AlertController:@"Alert!" :@"Request time out"];
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                        NSString *success = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"success"]stringValue];
                                                        if (
                                                            [success isEqualToString:
                                                             @"1"])
                                                        {
                                                            districList=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"data"]];
                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                                                            });

                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                           // [self AlertController:@"Alert!" :@"No record found"];
                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                                                            });

                                                        }

                                                    }

                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}




-(void)get_register_data
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    NSString *strURL;
    http://bullionscope.com/Gold_Phase3/webservices/get_all_province.php?request=ios

    strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bullionscope.com/Gold_Phase3/webservices/get_all_province.php?request=ios"];


    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"900e1577-4876-cd9a-d24c-cb0631b4a1fb" };


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        // [self AlertController:@"Alert!" :@"Request time out"];
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                        NSString *success = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"success"]stringValue];
                                                        if (
                                                            [success isEqualToString:
                                                             @"1"])
                                                        {

                                                            provinceList=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"data"]];

                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            // [self AlertController:@"Alert!" :@"No record found"];
                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                                                            });

                                                        }

                                                    }

                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post your complete class ? project size is 700mb.

Comment: Meanwhile i have downloaded the project , please give me few minutes.

Comment: It is always going in else statement .

Comment: how to display record in table view ?

Comment: Just one piece of advice, do not share your whole code project here , you are exposing all of your apis and code , be careful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api is returning nil data .

here is the error description -

```
Error Description: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
```

Problem is with your api handling .

This replace method in your GeneralWebservices class with this

```
    +(void) webserviceMainSplashCall:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters webserviceName:(NSString*)webserviceName OnCompletion:(void(^)(id returnDict, NSError* error))callbackBlock{
    /*
     // parameter keys & values, values will be dynamic.
     "forward_date" = "26-05-2016";
     "gold_weight" = 345;
     request = ios;
     "user_id" = 1;
     */

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",App_BaseUrl,webserviceName];
    NSLog(@"url is this = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",App_BaseUrl,webserviceName]);
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonReponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    // This will make the AFJSONResponseSerializer accept any content type
    jsonReponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
    manager.responseSerializer = jsonReponseSerializer;

//    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/html",@"text/json", @"text/javascript", nil];
//    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",App_BaseUrl,webserviceName] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    }
         progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
    {

    }
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
    {
        callbackBlock( responseObject, nil );
    }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
    {
        // check error here.
        NSLog(@"Error Description: %@",error);
        callbackBlock( nil, nil );
    }];
}
```

final screen shot of output -

[image]

Comment: Can record displayed in table view?app is crashing.how to get rid of app crashing ?

Comment: will need updated code, can you post the error here?

Comment: The issue is that  record is not displayed in "Transaction History" table view ?

Comment: after making this change in GeneralWebservices.m i got following error // manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]; //Error//Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd32712b000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010714026b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: how to display record in  table view of "Transaction History"?

Comment: to launch to dashboard please login with username and password provided above (username :hermon_yonaito@bullionscope.com
password :Wau2017?  ) .from dashboard you will see  "Transaction History" button on clicking it will load table view there will be no record in it .how to display record in table view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161952/discussion-between-mandeep-kumar-and-ajadka).

Comment: There is second issue please help.